# How to access a specific table in mysql using spring-mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I am new to spring-mvc. I am using it with **maven dependencies and JDBC Template**.

I can access to my database but can't seem to find any answer about how I can set up my connection so that spring-mvc would put data to a specific table in that database. So in short I am trying to access a specific table through spring-mvc in same database. I tried researching but could not find any answer.

This is database access in `dispatch.xml` looks like:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user" />
    <!--  property name="connectionProperties" value="useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;" -->
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" /> 
</bean>
```

Here is the DAO implementation-

```
@Component
public class PerformDaoImplmnt implements PerformDao {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    private static final String SQL_INSERT = "insert into user (name, password, email, area, phone) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    private static final String SQL_UPDATE = "update user set password=?, email=?, area=?, phone=? where name=?";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_ONE = "select * from user where name = ?";
    private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL = "select * from user order by phone";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE = "delete from user where phone  = ?";

    @Override
    public UserData findOne(long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public List<UserData> findAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String insert(UserData user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        int row = jdbc.update(SQL_INSERT, new Object[] { user.getFullName(), user.getPass(), user.getEmail(), 
                user.getArea(), user.getNumber()});

        if(row == 1){
            return "success";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(UserData user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(UserData user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

After this, 
This is how i am inserting data in my database-

```
    @Controller
public class Register {

    @Autowired
    PerformDao userDao;
    @RequestMapping(value="/processRegistration", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processRegistrationForm(@Valid   @ModelAttribute("user") UserData user, BindingResult result,
            RedirectAttributes redirect){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            ModelAndView backToRegisterPage = new ModelAndView("register");
            return backToRegisterPage;
        }
        ModelAndView profilePage = new ModelAndView();
        profilePage.setViewName("redirect:profile");
        String something = userDao.insert(user);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("user",user);
        return profilePage;
    }
```

I have two table in this "user" database. For example-

1. admin
2. normal

How do i access each individually. Please help. Thank you.

**I apologize. I know what to do. Just change table name in query. Its a dumb question after i understood what to do. Sorry guys**

Comment: you used `<property name="password" value="root" />`. Your db password is `root`?

Comment: where is your Java code ? Publish here

Comment: Hey Jason. It's more of a spring JDBC template question rather than spring mvc. Regardless of what spring framework you are using you should just be able to import JDBC template and connect to the database. Heaps of tutorials on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find complete solution
[spring JDBC](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_framework.htm).